# Fitting n number of squares into n area

Tags: geometry

I am a mobile developer and I have a problem and need to find a formula to get the dimensions of squares to fit inside a space. My problem is that I have a rectangle of dimensions lxw and need to fit n number of squares into it. Where n can change to any number from 2 up to 30 or more. While l and w can be any dimension but will mainly be in the range upward of 600x400. What I need is to fit exactly n number of squares into this space, the dimensions of the squares can go as small or as large as required.

Also I require the the number of rows and columns that will fit these squares in them. The squares will be displayed as evenly as possible across these rows and columns.

I have found a similar solution but I simply don't have the mathematics undestanding to get my head around the explanation. Also the explanation mentions that the grid is 'w squares wide, h squares high' however I don't know how many squares high and wide my screen will be, maybe I'm misunderstanding something? If someone could dumb this formula down for me it would be appreciated.

[How can I calculate the size of a square block and the number of rows and columns needed to fit a known number of blocks on a page of known size?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332939/how-can-i-calculate-the-size-of-a-square-block-and-the-number-of-rows-and-column)

Comment: Must they be strictly speaking squares, or can they be rectangles?

Comment: Preferably squares but rectangles will suffice if absolutely necessary and if it makes the formula easier to read.

Comment: Well my thought is that the dimensions of the screen might be limiting. The ratio of the number of squares on each side has to be the same as the ratio of the screen dimensions you'll be displaying on (of course you can remove some if you have to, but to make it fill the screen and look good, they have to be similar).

Comment: I see your point with that, I think I will require gaps between my squares. I  will re-work my question based off you advice. I have made edits to my original question but I think I still require another formula as mentioned in my edits.

Comment: What if $n = 37$? You said you want exactly $n$ squares, but you didn't specify how you want the squares to be arranged...

Comment: I have made edits to my question to reflect you query. I want the the squares to be at maximum size for the space required and to be displayed  in rows and columns. I'm beginning to think that this formula may be alot harder than I first thought.

Comment: Could you please clarify the relationship between your question and the one you linked to? You call it a "similar question", but the only difference I could identify is that the other question says the screen will always be in landscape mode -- so wouldn't it be more accurate to say that you're actually reasking that question? In that case, you should state that more clearly and try to describe more specifically what it is about the existing answer to the existing question that you're asking about; otherwise this would be a duplicate of the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding another question which basically answered my question. It has alot of maths behind it which I don't understand but he put a C code example so I was able to follow that and understand what I needed to do. Link is posted below

[Algorithm to get the maximum size of n squares that fit into a rectangle with a given width and height](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466198/algorithm-to-get-the-maximum-size-of-n-squares-that-fit-into-a-rectangle-with-a)